# object_to_array and encode - php to js opbject

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I send Ajax call to AjaxHandler.php page, the AjaxHandler page call other function in Functions.php (other page).

On success i need to return object from AjaxHandler.php, the object need to have 2 params.

Here is the ajax call:

```
var month_number = document.getElementById("Month").innerHTML;
var year_number = document.getElementById("Year").innerHTML;
$.get("AjaxHandler.php", { "year": year_number, "month": month_number }, function (encodedata) {
    var data = JSON.parse(encodedata);
    $("#LinesPlace").html(data);
});
```

Here is the AjaxHandler.php code the need to handle that:

```
if(isset($_GET['year'],$_GET['month']))
{
  $year = $_GET['year'];
  $month = $_GET['month'];
  $a =  getExpenses($year, $month);
  echo $a->pharama;
  echo $a->pharamb;
  $b = object_to_array($a);
  echo $b;
  return json_encode($b);
}
```

Now when i put that url:

```
http://xxxxxxxxx.com/AjaxHandler.php?year=2015&month=09
```

Its show me the echo of pharama and pharamb but when i try to convert the object to array and then decode it its just not working, i tryed alot but nothing.

Here is the object_to_array function:

```
//convert php object to array
function object_to_array($data){
    if(is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        $result = array();

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key] = $this->object_to_array($value);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

*I taked that function from this site from other question..

Please advice =]

Regards,
Rafael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rafael I cant comment need 50 rep or something:D You say: *What you mean unnecessary? you mean i can return the object php as is?*

Half of what if am saying: you know the things you put into the function obj_to_array() rigth? That what goes in and it ain't an object so why check it? Who will send it? Do you foresee a $_POST incomming all wrapped up as a nice object and ready to go? Like normally the form does a $_POST / $_GET and provides arrays by default as far as I know? And if you produce an obj elsewhere in your code why put use it as input for this function? Don't you know what you are doing somewhere else in your code? Sure you do and as long as you are concise and precise it will never suddenly be a object returned form $_POST or any function normally outputting arrays or integers etc. Check your output as you created it in the first place? Check your web inputs very well (1 time! and for js injections), then only check your types for validating ambiguous output / inputs of your own like an output that can produce an array or a true / false return value. Checking this output for a value of 1 for a TRUE value of the boolean can result in disappointment  because:

if the value of $a is 1 in if($a) do something; then a 1 can be the TRUE value returned as the result of the function that produced the thing that we are checking or the result of count($a). If we then assume the array is length 1 because of a misinterpretation of the value of $a then this can give unintended results? You want to be sure that it is the array in $_array($a) that's doing the talking and not the array for example? Thats all to it I think? Or am I rambling (again)?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to decode the JSON as an array or object, `json_decode` has a parameter specifically for that: http://php.net/json_decode

> `mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )`
>   ...
>   **assoc**
>   When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

For example:

```
$json_as_object = json_decode($json, false);
$json_as_array  = json_decode($json, true);
```

Attempting to manually convert an object into an array should be unnecessary.

Comment: What you mean unnecessary? you mean i can return the object php as is? please explaine..

Comment: @Rafael - I mean you can decode the JSON directly to an array instead of decoding to an object and trying to translate it into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode it very specifically with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE like this:

$jsonObj = json_encode ( string $json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

I have this code in a standard function for this sort of thing

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

PS. I think you are over checking it in your object to array function. I would probably choose something like: if(is_array($param)){ .. }

Comment: well at the end i use this ajax:

$.ajax({
        url: "AjaxHandler.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { "year": year_number, "month": month_number },
        dataType: "json", // jQuery will now parse the returned data and return an object
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                //now you can acess navlos, besedilo and datum
                var test = obj;
                $('#LinesPlace').html('<div>' + obj + '</div>');
            });
        }
    });

and now its ok...=]

Comment: Mr Lama I cant comment need 50 rep or something:D What you mean unnecessary? you mean i can return the object php as is?